# DB2 SQL count in join or where clause

Tags: sql, count, db2

This is probably an amateur question but I'm an amateur !  ;o)

I have several tables: Account table, Officer table, Location table, Web table...
The Officer table doesn't give me the number of officers per account.

I need to retrieve only the accounts that have more than 20 officers.
Should I use the COUNT ?  If so, how ?

Your help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Pat

Comment: Please post your schema. How are Accounts related to Officers?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

```
select a.id, a.eff-date, l.address, l.city, c.phonenumber
from Account a 
left outer join location l on a.id = l.id
left outer join contact c on a.id = c.id
where a.id in (
    select a.id
    from Account a
    inner join Officer ao on a.id = ao.id
    group by a.id
    having count(*) > 20    
)
```

Comment: ok.. here's the problem

account table (id, eff-date etc)
join officer table (id, officer number)
join location table (id, address, city etc)
left join contact table (id, phone number etc.)
left join webinfo table (website, email, etc)

the goal is to display only the id's that have more than 20 officer number

sorry for the lack of explanations...  my bad !  thanks for your help.. really appreciate it

Comment: See my update. What are the relationships? Is the `id` column always representing Account ID?

Comment: yes id always representing account id... if i wanted to display id, eff-date, address, city, phone number when available but only those who have more than 20 officers... how would I code this ?